# Finite sum involving Stirling numbers

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, stirling-numbers

I am trying to evaluate the following finite sum:

$$
\sum_{h=0}^{m}\binom{m}{h}2^{m-h}S(h,k-r)S(m-h,r),\qquad 0\leq r\leq k\leq m,
$$

where $S(n,k)$ is the Stirling number of the second kind. Can you throw some light on it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This sum comes from the product of the exponential generating function of the Stirling numbers of the second kind with itself. The number of blocks in the first egf is $k-r$; the number of blocks in the other is $r$. The factor of $2^{m-h}$ can be accounted for by a factor of 2 in the variable of the second egf. Since the egf of the Stirling numbers of the second kind partitioned into $k$ blocks is $\frac{(e^x-1)^k}{k!}$, your sum is the coefficient of $x^m$ in $$\frac{(e^x-1)^{k-r}}{(k-r)!}\frac{(e^{2x}-1)^r}{r!}.$$
Algebraically, this simplifies to $\frac{(e^x-1)^k}{(k-r)!}\frac{(e^x+1)^r}{r!}$, which can be expanded with the binomial theorem to get a nice sum.

Edit:

Your sum is $[x^m]\frac{1}{r!(k-r)!}(e^x-1)^k (e^x+1)^r$ which, by the product formula, is
$$\frac{1}{r!(k-r)!}\sum_{n=0}^m[x^n](e^x-1)^k\cdot [x^{m-n}](e^x+1)^r.$$
By the binomial theorem this is
$$\frac{1}{r!(k-r)!}\sum_{n=0}^m\left(\sum_{\ell=0}^k\binom k\ell(-1)^{k-\ell}[x^n]e^{\ell x}\cdot\sum_{s=0}^r \binom rs[x^{m-n}]e^{sx}\right).$$
Extracting the coefficients, your sum is equivalent to
$$\frac{1}{r!(k-r)!}\sum_{n=0}^m\left(\sum_{\ell=0}^k\binom k\ell(-1)^{k-\ell}\frac{\ell^n}{n!}\cdot\sum_{s=0}^r \binom rs\frac{s^{m-n}}{(m-n)!}\right).$$

Comment: Thank you! But this is exactly where I came from ^_^

Comment: That's funny! I added an expansion with the binomial theorem to get an explicit answer in terms of binomial coefficients. However, on second thought this is probably the same result as expressing the Stirling numbers themselves in terms of binomial coefficients.

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable suggestion... now I need time to meditate ;)

Answer (score 0):

By a combinatorial argument, perhaps it is also possible from the generating function you already have, you can arrive to the following recursion formula.
$$A_{a,b,c}=cA_{a-1,b,c}+A_{a-1,b-1,c-1}+2(b-c)A_{a-1,b,c}+2A_{a-1,b-1,c},$$with initial values $A_{a,b,c}=0$ if $a<0$ or $b<0$ or $c<0$ or $a<b$ or $b<c$ and $A_{a,b,c}=\binom{b}{c}2^{b-c}$ if $a=b$.
The combinatorial argument is by counting the number of partitions$\lambda = \{B_i\}_{1\leq i\leq k}$ in the colored set $[a]$ with $3$ colors such that in each block $B_i$ if $x\in B_i$ and $x$ is colored with $0$ or $1$ then no element of $B_i$ is colored with color $2$. Also, the numbers of blocks in which each element is colored by $2$ is $c$.
Your formula counts the number of that kind of partitions by splitting in two the set $[a]$, the ones that are colored by $2$,counted $\binom{m}{h}S_{h,k-r}$ and the ones that are colored by $0,1$ counted $2^{m-h}S_{m-h,r}$.
In the recursion, the process is the same but adding in each step a new element. So $cA_{a-1,b,c}$ is the number of ways you can put a new element colored by $2$ in the $c$ blocks you have, $A_{a-1,b-1,c-1}$ is to create a new block with the new element colored by $2$, $2(b-c)A_{a-1,b,c}$ is to put a new element colored by $0$ or $1$ in the $b-c$ blocks and $2A_{a-1,b-1,c}$ is to create a new class to put a new element colored by $0$ or $1$.
I do not know how to come up with a closed expression but i hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! Now I need time to think about this!

Comment: You are welcome. If you come up with something be free to post here. I am trying too.